# Does a "Push To Beam" workaround exist?

Tags: android, nfc

I am currently trying to implement a basic NFC app on the Nexus 7.

I have been able to transmit an NDEF record (Web Url) using the Beam SDK but i'm stuck with the "Tap to beam" UI, like many others on here.

I am aware that there is no way to disable this screen or automatically press it, but, are the re any other possible workarounds?

For example, a colleague has just suggested something like putting the Nexus 7 in `tag writer mode` and then getting the other app into `tag read mode`.

Or am I correct in saying that NFC in Android can only be used to read/write NFC tags and also share items using beam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFC chip continuously switches between Reader/Writer mode and peer-to-peer mode (and card emulation, if you have Google Wallet installed). In Reader/Writer mode, it can communicate with an NFC tag. Two devices in Reader/Writer mode cannot communicate with each other; that is what peer-to-peer mode was invented for. Peer-to-peer mode is what is used for Android Beam.

It is also not possible to use the card emulation mode on one device. First of all, an Android device will not detect the card emulation on another Android device (it prefers to do peer-to-peer). Secondly, your app would need special permission to access the Secure Element (that does the card emulation) from the OS. And, thirdly, even if you would manage to tackle these hurdles, there is still no way to write data to the Secure Element, as you don't have the necessary access control keys to do it.

So to answer your original question: there is no way to circumvent the Android Beam UI by switching to other NFC modes. Sorry.

**UPDATE:**

As of Android 4.4 Kitkat, apps have the possibility to emulate a card using so-called [Host Card Emulation (HCE)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html). For an app on another Android NFC device to communicate with such an emulated tag, it needs to use a new [NFC Reader Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode%28android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) (which disables Android Beam entirely to prevent it from getting in the way).

Comment: Exactly as I thought. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Card emulation now exists in Android as of OS version 4.4. Here is the Android documentation about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html